# How can I prevent a Pixel 6 from changing focus while recording a video with the native camera application?

Tags: android-12, video-recording, google-pixel-6, focus

For example, if I record a video from behind a window, I tried to put the focus on whatever I'm looking it behind the window, but if something happens on the window while I'm recording, such as rain on the window, Pixel 6 may decide to focus on the window, suddenly and at any time.

How can I prevent a Pixel 6 from changing focus while recording a video with the native camera application? I use Android 12.

Comment: Since the question mentioned "the native camera application", I believe this issue affects the Google Camera app and independent of a specific model since it behaves the same on Pixel 3a. AFAIK, the app has auto AF-lock after a few seconds, but I can't find a way to force-lock the focus while recording.

Comment: The trouble with Google's camera software in all the Google Pixel phones is that it tries to be too smart and doesn't allow you to do what you actually want.  I guess that's part of Google's "we know what's best for you" corporate mentality.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks, feel free to post it an answer. I've posted an app recommendation question: [Video recording app for Pixel 6 that can record in 4K 60 FPS and allow users to disable the autofocus](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/85083/903)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket sounds about right :/